# After second triggered function button inside execute code twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make a game and I have problem that I cant solve.
I have function and inside I have buttons with .click(). After I execute function for second time buttons clicks execute code twice for example I post here some simple code with same problem.

When I click 1st button alert is triggered once. When I click 2nd and then 1st button alert is triggered twice. I want trigger alert just once. Buttons must stay in function. Sorry for bad English.

Also jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/25237/

```
function testf() {
  $("#1").click(function() {
    alert("test");
  });

  $("#2").click(function() {
    testf();
   });
}

testf();
```

Comment: It's because you're nesting the event handler creation in `testf()`. In turn, clicking `#2` adds another click handler to each element. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i space game. Function generate planets and objects in space. With buttons you control the ship to jump form planet to planet. After you visit all planet you can jump to another solar system and when you do it that is when i need call function again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unbind the click event before bind,

```
function testf() {
  $("#1").unbind('click');
  $("#1").click(function() {
    alert("test");
  });

  $("#2").unbind('click');    
  $("#2").click(function() {
    testf();
  });
}
testf();
```

Comment: 1) `unbind()` is deprecated, don't use it. Use `off()` instead. 2) The OP is simply using the incorrect pattern of nested event handlers. There's no need to unbind anything if you structure them properly.

Comment: Thanks man, unbind works perfectly in my game. Can you explain me why is bad idea to use it?

Comment: @Jac0b it's because there's no reason to dynamically add/remove click handlers at runtime if the UI logic is designed properly. Doing this is a code smell of a larger issue which should be addressed first, instead of using this as a band-aid.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this function is binding your event twice. changing anything here removes the issue

```
  $(".address_field").each(function(index){  
var widget = new AddressFinder.Widget(this, "WR3NUKVGC4Q97FPHBJXL");
```